# How do I copy an entire column(including the datatype) from an sqlite table to another table using python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to write a function for removing columns in sqlite(Because sometimes I might want to delete columns which are too old).

Comment: Is the other table in the same database, or a different one?

Comment: It's not clear what your schema is, but you might want to re-think your schema design if you have to regularly delete "too old" columns.

Comment: @Keith: I can't tell what OP is doing, but a common use-case for this is upgrading an application. When the schema changes between versions, the new version needs to have a code to alter the tables appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11):

> SQLite has limited ALTER TABLE support
>   that you can use to add a column to
>   the end of a table or to change the
>   name of a table. If you want to make
>   more complex changes in the structure
>   of a table, you will have to recreate
>   the table. You can save existing data
>   to a temporary table, drop the old
>   table, create the new table, then copy
>   the data back in from the temporary
>   table.
>
> For example, suppose you have a table
>   named "t1" with columns names "a",
>   "b", and "c" and that you want to
>   delete column "c" from this table. The
>   following steps illustrate how this
>   could be done:
>
> ```
>     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
>     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
>     INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
>     DROP TABLE t1;
>     CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
>     INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
>     DROP TABLE t1_backup;
>     COMMIT;
> ```

Comment: It would be easier `ALTER TABLE` to rename the old table out of the way, copy the data just once and drop the old table instead. The double copy might result in more compact database though.